# VBA Compile Error, Trying to copy sheet from external file to master file

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a compile error on this code, I am trying to target `SourceFileName` without opening and load it into my active workbook sheet "data retrieval"

I am getting `compile error, sub of function not defined`.

```
Sub test()

Set appxl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
Dim myfile As Window
Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Double
Dim sourceFileName As String
 
sourceFileName = "File name"
 
'Open Source File.xlsx
With appxl
    .Workbooks.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & sourceFileName
    .Visible = False
End With
  
'Get first sheet data
Set myfile = appxl.Windows(sourceFileName)
myfile.Activate
Set currentSheet = appxl.Sheets(12)
 
'Past the table in my current Excel file
lastRow = currentSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Sheets("Data retrieval").Range("A1:E" & lastRow) = currentSheet.Range("A1:E" & lastRow).Value
 
'Close Source File.xlsx
appxl.Workbooks(sourceFileName).Close

End Sub
```

After applying the below recommendation of `Option Explicit` and declaring `appxl` I am getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: You need to declare `appxl`. This compiles on my end though

Comment: @Pᴇʜ very start.

Comment: @excelguy you can be more specific here..... which line? The very start as in `Sub test()`?

Comment: @urdearboy yes that line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the following

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim AppXl As Excel.Application
    Set AppXl = New Excel.Application
    AppXl.Visible = False

    Dim sourceFileName As String
    sourceFileName = "File name"

    'Open Source File.xlsx
    Dim SourceWb As Workbook 'remember workbook in a variable so we can easily access it
    Set SourceWb = AppXl.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sourceFileName)

    'Get first sheet data
    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
    Set currentSheet = SourceWb.Sheets(12)

    'Past the table in my current Excel file
    Dim lastRow As Long 'row counting variables MUST be Long
    lastRow = currentSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    'define the workbook here
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data retrieval").Range("A1:E" & lastRow).Value = currentSheet.Range("A1:E" & lastRow).Value

    'Close Source File.xlsx
    SourceWb.Close SaveChanges:=False 'close source without saving
    AppXl.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks,but now getting a new error. See edited question.

Comment: @excelguy quit all instances of Excel (or restart your computer). And try again. Always provide **in which line** you get an error otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: its kind of just repeating that error . I believe it was at ` Set SourceWb = AppXl.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sourceFileName)` . Going to try restarting.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I believe"*? You should be sure. The code line that throws the error is highlighted in yellow.

Comment: I cant see the yellow, it doesnt show it. This error doesnt cause a debug option.

Comment: Go through your code step by step using F8. This way you always know in which line you are.

Comment: Ok sir, yes i stepped through it. it is line , `Set SourceWb = AppXl.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sourceFileName)` .  Now im confused more. `Thisworkbook`  is taking my active workbook where I want the data to be pasted, `sourcefilename` is the place i want to copy from. Why is it concatenating these two.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184038/discussion-between-p-and-excelguy).